InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket
I am trying to create a CloudTrail at the organizational level using Terraform but encountering an error related to the S3 bucket policy.
I have tried to use AWS Docs for the policy, tried to use policy from my manually created S3 Bucket for Trail logging but unsuccessfully.
# Create the S3 bucket for CloudTrail logs
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "cloudtrail_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.organization_name}-cloudtrail-logs"
}

# Apply server-side encryption using AWS-managed keys (SSE-S3)
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "cloudtrail_bucket_sse" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}

# Block public access for this S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "cloudtrail_bucket_block_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id

  restrict_public_buckets = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
}
# Bucket policy for CloudTrail logging
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "cloudtrail_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.arn}/${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.name}"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/AWSLogs/${var.account_id}/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "AWS:SourceArn": "${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.arn}/${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.name}",
            "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailOrganizationWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/AWSLogs/${var.organization_id}/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "AWS:SourceArn": "${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.arn}/${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.name}",
            "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}



# CloudTrail resource
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "cloudtrail" {
  name                          = "${var.organization_name}-organizational-Trail"
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id
  include_global_service_events = true
  is_multi_region_trail         = true
  enable_log_file_validation    = true
  is_organization_trail         = true

  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "WriteOnly"
    include_management_events = true
  }
}

And there is the same error:

 Error: creating CloudTrail Trail: operation error CloudTrail: CreateTrail, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: fcc97f0b-483b-4eaa-9650-c56a10b9c3c6, InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket
│ 
│   with aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail,
│   on main.tf line 84, in resource "aws_cloudtrail" "cloudtrail":
│   84: resource "aws_cloudtrail" "cloudtrail" {

I am consistently getting the error: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket. Any suggestions on what might be missing or how to correct the bucket policy?

Rather than looking at the Terraform code, it might be easier to debug if you look at the actual Bucket Policy that Terraform applied to the bucket and then compare it to the documentation. Can you add that 'actual' policy to your Question?

I have resolved the issue:
"aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:eu-west-1:${var.account.id}:trail/${var.organization_name}-organizational-Trail"

I had to enter the ARN manually for some reason, as CloudTrail's ARN was not passed to the policy when I was using:
"AWS:SourceArn": "${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.arn}/${aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail.name}"


Great work solving your issue. Please accept your own answer.
